# Drozd's trichotomy theorem for finite-dimensional algebras over any field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $K$. Then the classical Drozd's trichotomy asserts that the representation type of $A$ is either finite, tame or wild type.

I was convinced that this result still holds for any characteristic but I could not find any good references for it, so I have started to wonder if that is true or not. Is it true?

Anyway, what concerns more to me is if even if the trichotomy may not hold for arbitrary finite-dimensional algebras over an arbitrary field, is it true for hereditary algebras at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an indecomposable finite dimensional hereditary algebra $H$ over an arbitrary field $K$, there is such a trichotomy.

The algebra $H$ has finite representation type if and only if the symmetric bilinear form on the Grothendieck group is positive definite, if and only if it is of Dynkin type, if and only if there are no regular modules. In this case all modules are both preprojective and preinjective, and taking the class of a module yields a bijection between the isoclasses of indecomposable modules and the set of positive roots of the Dynkin diagram.

The algebra $H$ has tame representation type if and only if the symmetric bilinear form is positive semi-definite (but not positive definite), if and only if it is of extended Dynkin type, if and only if the regular modules form a thick abelian subcategory. In this case taking the class of a module yields a surjection from isoclasses of indecomposable modules and the set of positive roots. For each positive real root, there is a unique such isoclass of indecomposables. For each multiple of the minimal positive imaginary root the set of such isoclasses has cardinality at least that of the field $K$. Moreover, the regular modules come in tubular families, and the tubes are indexed by the closed points of a regular normal curve over $K$.

The algebra $H$ has wild representation type if and only if the symmetric bilinear form is indefinite. In this general setting the Kac-type result on the classes of indecomposables is not known (it does hold over finite fields or algebraically closed fields though).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Once that the dichotomy is established for hereditary algebras I wonder if from the characterization you have shown could it be deduced that a finite-dimensional hereditary algebra of infinite type s.t. for every natural number $n$ there is at most a finite number of indecomposable modules of length $n$ is of tame representation type? I see that if the field $K$ is infinite the answer is true, but I do not see it clearly for $K$ finite.

Comment: Any such characterization will fail for algebras over a finite field. For each $n$ there can only ever be finitely many isoclasses of $n$ dimensional modules, independent of the representation type.

Comment: I see, thanks.  But if we further impose that for every $n$-dimensional vector $d$ , where $n$ is the number of simple modules up to isomorphism,  there is at most one indecomposable module of with dimension vector $d$ then it is automatically of tame type, right? My problem is that I could not find a good reference of how to define formally tame and wild type over non-algebraically closed fields in terms of $1$-parameter families and embeddings of the free algebra $K[x,y]$, so I am not sure about this.

Comment: For a finite dimensional tame hereditary algebra, the minimal positive imaginary root is sincere, so has dimension at least $n$, with equality in affine type $A$. In particular, the Kronecker quiver is tame but fails your condition.

Comment: The notion of one-parameter families can be expressed in terms of generic modules, which are indecomposable, infinite dimensional, but finite length over their endomorphism rings (=endofinite). This definition works over any field, and every tame hereditary algebra has precisely one generic module (up to iso). Its endoring is central simple, with centre the function field of the regular normal curve alluded to in the main answer.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I understand the comments and the main answer, a finite-dimensional hereditary algebra with my condition must be of finite representation type, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146197/discussion-between-blascule787-and-andrew-hubery).